# how to make all elements on a page wider

Tags: html, css

So I am making a test website and I all text images, and navigation text is in the middle of the page and there is a lot of space on the side. how can I use more of the space on the side?

Comment: You have to be more specific than this.

Comment: What exactly you are looking?

Answer (score 1):

Use your CSS to define the size of your main content.  If pixel size (say width:1000px) isn't enough, then set the width to width:100%.

In any case, you are going to have to do some serious research on CSS and how to use it.

Comment: Alternatively, OP might want to increase the `word-spacing` or `letter-spacing` -- depending on what he/she means by "make all elements on a page wider."